Terraform data source (from aws provider) aws_vpc_ipam_pools not returning expected results
I am using the aws_vpc_ipam_pools data source to return a list of IPAM pools in an AWS account.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/vpc_ipam_pools.html
However, I am only getting a partial list of IPAM pools unless I filter for a specific IPAM pool ID.
This is how I am using the data source. There are 10 IPAM pools in the account that match the criteria specified in the filter and I only get 3 returned in the ipam_pools list. For some reason, when I query by specific IPAM pool IDs, I am able to get results that are not included in the list when using any other filter.
data "aws_vpc_ipam_pools" "ipv6_pools" {
  provider = aws

  filter {
    name   = "address-family"
    values = ["ipv6"]
  }
}

My immediate thought is that it may have something to do with the fact that 7/10 of the IPAM pools are nested, but at least one nested IPAM pool is always returned when querying with the filter above.
Terraform version = 1.9.1
AWS provider version = 5.57.0

Can you elaborate further? Are there any differences between the pools you are trying to fetch? For example, do they have different names maybe?

There aren't any major differences between the pools aside from the descriptions and names. I don't think differences in either of those should prevent Terraform from returning them when the filter should capture all IPv6 pools. The name attribute also happens to be just the description and pool ID together.

Are they all in the same region?

Yes, they are all in the same region as well.

Hm, ok, any reason to specify the provider explicitly in the data source?

Originally, I was specifying a different provider with access to a different account to retrieve the data. The provider that's specified in the code above is actually just the default provider for that module, I just never took that line out.

Are they all IPv6 only?
